# Como fazer resto da divisao de um float por um numero em c?

Tags: c, matriz, float

Sou iniciante em programar em c, tenho aqui um problema o exercício e calcular a media dos ímpares numa matriz que recebe números reais. No entanto, estou tendo o seguinte erro:

> error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'float' and 'int')

eis o código:

```
float mediaImpar(float a[4][4]){
    int count=0;
    float soma=0;
    for(int l=0;l<2;l++)
        for(int c=0;c<2;c++){
            if(a[l][c]%2!=0){
                soma=a[l][c]+soma;
                count++;
            }}
     float media=soma/count;
     return media;
    //return countPrimo;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    float numero;
    float a[2][2];
    for(int l=0;l<2;l++){
        for(int c=0;c<2;c++){
            printf("Digite na linha %d e coluna %d \t", l, c);
            scanf("%f",&numero);
            a[l][c]=numero;
        }
    }
    float m=mediaImpar(a);
    printf("%f",m);



    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

como solucionar esse problema, e qual e a causa?

Comment: tentei essa tambem , o tem erro semelhante.  error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'float' and 'double')

Comment: Primeiro me explique o o que é um resto de *float*. Na matemática isto não existe.

Answer (score 1):

O operador resto da divisão, o `%`, também chamado de modulo, **só pode ser usado entre inteiros**. No código está a ser usado entre `floats`, aqui:

```
if (a[l][c] % 2 != 0){
//    ^-float ^-int
```

Pois a matriz `a` foi criada com o tipo `float`.

Para fazer a mesma operação entre `floats` é necessário utilizar a função [`fmod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/) da biblioteca `math.h`:

```
#include <math.h>

...

if (fmod(a[l][c], 2) != 0){
//   ^----
```

Atenção que variáveis do tipo `float` ou `double`, podem apresentar algumas imprecisões nos valores armazenados, e por isso um `if` desse gênero pode nem sempre funcionar.

[Documentação da função `fmod` caso queira consultar](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/)

Answer (score 0):

Conforme o site http://www.matematica.pt/faq/numero-par.php:
"Primeiro a definição de número PAR apenas pode ser aplicada a números inteiros. Posto isto, um número é par se ao ser dividido pelo número dois, o resultado é num número inteiro. Utilizando a linguagem matemática, "par é todo número que pode ser escrito na forma 2n", com n pertencente ao conjunto dos números inteiros"
Assim 8 é par pois 2 x 4 = 8.

Uma forma de analisar isso em programação é através da muito utilizada função MOD ou Resto da divisão inteira. Se o resto de um numero dividido por dois for zero(0) ele será par! Caso contrário, se o resto da divisão inteira por 2 for diferente != de zero o número será impar.

Veja o código abaixo. Fiz pequenas modificações, estude o código e tente fazer sozinho. Bom Estudo

```
/*Calcula a media dos ímpares numa matriz que recebe números INTEIROS*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float mediaImpar(int a[4][4]); //protótipo da função

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int numero, linha, coluna;
    int matriz[4][4]; //declara uma matriz 4 x 4 com linhas e colunas 0,1,2 e 3
    float media = 0.0;
    for(linha = 0; linha < 4; linha++){
        for(coluna = 0; coluna < 4; coluna++){
            system("CLS"); //limpa a tela
            printf("Entre com o elemento matriz[%d][%d]: ", linha+1, coluna+1);
            scanf("%d", &matriz[linha][coluna]);

        }//fim for
    }//fim for
    media = mediaImpar(matriz); //chama a função
    printf("====A matriz digitada====\n\n");
    for(linha = 0; linha < 4; linha++){
         for (coluna = 0; coluna < 4; coluna++){
             printf("%2d ", matriz[linha][coluna] );
             if (coluna == 3)
               printf ("\n");
         } //fim for
    } //fim for
    printf("\nMedia dos números impares da matriz: %.2f",media);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
} //fim main

float mediaImpar(int a[4][4]){
    int count = 0, i, j;
    int soma = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if(a[i][j] % 2 != 0){
                soma += a[i][j]; // o mesmo que soma = soma + a[i][j];
                count++;
            }//fim if
         }//fim for
     }//fim for
     float media = (float)soma/count; //cast para que o resultado da media seja float
     return media;

} //fim mediaImpar
```

Veja a saída do programa ao ser executado:
[image: Saída do código acima]